# Binding a DataGridView to a DataSet directly fails

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datasource

A DataGridView bound by this code does not display information as expected:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

here's the code for ds:

```
public DataSet ConnectandReadList()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string connection_string="Data Source=hermes;database=qcvalues; Integrated Security=SSPI;";            

            using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
            {

                myConnection.Open();
                var command = new SqlCommand(InitializeQuery(), myConnection);
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }


            return ds;
        }
```

Comment: A DataSet is a collection of DataTables. You need to specify a DataTable to be bound to the DataGridView. Otherwise, it doesn't know which DataTable to use, even if there is only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try binding to the table inside the dataset:  `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

From the documentation for the [DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) property, you can also bind to a `DataSet` and use the `DataMember` property:

> When binding to a data source that contains multiple lists or tables, you must set the DataMember property to a string that specifies the list or table to bind to.

I think in this case the table name would be "Table" since you are not naming it explicitly.

Comment: HELL YEAH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!. can u please explain why i needed to do this?

Comment: Not exactly sure, other than that I don't think the datagridview is smart enough to look into the dataset for its tables.  Never thought to look into it further...

Comment: +1 either this or set the datagridview1.DataMember to the table name but since you don't manually create it the above is easier.

Comment: Guess this is also why you wanted to debug the DataSource? ;)

Comment: @Doggett, thanks, yes, just saw that bit about DataMember in the docs.  Will add that to the answer as additional info.

Answer (score 3):

Is ds a DataSet?

If so, try setting your DGV's DataMember to a DataTable within the DataSet or specifying your DataSet's DataTable for the DataSource.